# Issue with using Robot() to handle windows pop up

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

I am using `Robot()` to handle the windows pop up in my application. I have to pass `userId` and `password`. `userId` gets entered successfully but the same code doesn't work for `password`. Is there anything I am missing? I am using Selenium with Webdriver. Here is my sample code:

```
public void EnterUserId(String userId) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        Robot rb = new Robot();
        StringSelection username = new StringSelection(userId);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(username, null);
        rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        Reporter.reportStep("UserId has been entered", "PASS");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Reporter.reportStep("UserId has not been entered", "FAIL");
    }
}

public void EnterPassword(String password) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
        Robot rb = new Robot();
        StringSelection pwd = new StringSelection(password);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(pwd, null);
        rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
        rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        Reporter.reportStep("Password has been entered", "PASS");
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Reporter.reportStep("Password has not been entered", "FAIL");
    }
}
```

Comment: This is java not javascript

Comment: Please try `robot.delay(1000);` instead of `Thread.sleep();` and let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct me if I wrong: you try CTRL+C and CTRl+V password in this code:

```
StringSelection pwd = new StringSelection(password);
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(pwd, null);
```

setContents:
     * Sets the current contents of the clipboard to the specified
     * transferable object and registers the specified clipboard owner
     * as the owner of the new contents.*

But very often password field have protected for copy-paste action. Because of this it doesn't work.

Comment: yes am using Ctrl C, Ctrl V and luckily the action is not protected in my application

Comment: I should ask: are u sure about not protected? By hand input Ctrl C, Ctrl V works correct in password field?

Comment: yes, I increased the wait and it works. I myself am not sure how.. But somehow it works. Though this issue is resolved I am facing -https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45843818/unhandledalertexception-issue-for-windows-pop-up