# UnhandledAlertException issue for windows pop up

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, selenium-firefoxdriver

Hi I am using Robot() to handle windows pop up. I am getting UnhandledAlertException at

```
if (driver.getTitle().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(title)).
```

There are no more open alerts and yet the exception is thrown.

I tried using-

```
dc.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR, UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.IGNORE);
```

But then i get the issue for ignore- InvalidArgumentException

```
public void VerifyTitle(String title, String URL, String UserId, String Password) throws InterruptedException, IOException{

    driver.get(URL);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);     
    EnterUserId(UserId);        
    EnterPassword(Password);    
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    EnterUserId(UserId);        
    EnterPassword(Password);
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(50000, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    EnterUserId(UserId);
    EnterPassword(Password);

    try{        

        if (driver.getTitle().trim().equalsIgnoreCase(title)){
            System.out.println("PASS");

        }else
            System.out.println("FAIL");

    }catch (Exception e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

        System.out.println("FAIL");
    }       
}

public void EnterUserId(String userId) throws IOException{

    try{
    Robot rb = new Robot();     
    rb.delay(5000);
    StringSelection username = new StringSelection(userId);             
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(username, null);                       
    rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);               
    rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);             
    rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);               
    rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);
    rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);                   
    rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);             
    System.out.println("UserId has been entered");
    rb.delay(5000);

    }catch (Exception e) {          
        e.printStackTrace();            
        System.out.println("UserId has not been entered");
    }

}

public void EnterPassword(String password) throws IOException{

    try {    
    Robot rb = new Robot();     
    rb.delay(5000);
    StringSelection pwd = new StringSelection(password);        
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(pwd, null);        
    rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);        
    rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);             
    rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);               
    rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CONTROL);     
    rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);               
    rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);   
    rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);             
    rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);       
    System.out.println("Password has been entered");
    rb.delay(5000);     

    }catch (Exception e) {          
        e.printStackTrace();    
        System.out.println("Password has not been entered");
    }

}
```

And this is how am launching my browser-

```
@Parameters({"browserName"})
@BeforeTest
public void beforeTest(String browserName){     
    threadDriver = new ThreadLocal<RemoteWebDriver>();          
    if(browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")){
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\chromedriver.exe");          
        threadDriver.set(new ChromeDriver());  
    }else {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "D:\\geckodriver.exe");           
        DesiredCapabilities dc = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
        dc.setCapability(CapabilityType.UNEXPECTED_ALERT_BEHAVIOUR, UnexpectedAlertBehaviour.IGNORE);
        dc.setCapability("acceptInsecureCerts",true);   
        threadDriver.set(new FirefoxDriver(dc));  
    }           
}
```

Comment: Since, it's an alert, is there any 'OK' button also? If yes, where in your code you are clicking it?

Comment: Its an authentication pop up. So i just enter user id and pwd and click on enter.  here is the code to press enter  
    rb.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);             
    rb.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);

Comment: @AnuradhaKumari I am running into the same issue and have not found a resolution.

Comment: @smit9234 
If robot class also didn't work for you, try passing the id password along with url
Ex-
http://userid:password@url.com

Comment: @AnuradhaKumari  I am using AutoIT to fill out the windows authentication. That works fine, its when the rest of the test is trying to execute, geckodriver keeps thinking there is an alert present when there isn't. I posted on their github, https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/issues/977